# How to set multiple Tabs in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am getting a problem while setting tabs

[image: DAsh bord image]
[image: next image one of four tab activites]
I have to open four activity in tabs in next activity when user select one of four items from dashboard I am getting error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pradeep.amerifleet/com.pradeep.amerifleet.TabSelect}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear please?

Comment: i have posted image are u able to see the both images?

Comment: added images plz reply i need urgent